# Pandas dataframe assignment with .loc fails with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiindex and when I try to assign to a slice with `.loc` the resulting values in the dataframe are `NaN`s

I am using Jupyter Notebooks.

```py
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']])
print(columns)
MultiIndex([('A', 'a'),
            ('A', 'b'),
            ('A', 'c'),
            ('A', 'd'),
            ('A', 'e'),
            ('B', 'a'),
            ('B', 'b'),
            ('B', 'c'),
            ('B', 'd'),
            ('B', 'e')],
           )

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(3,10)), columns=columns)
print(df)
     A                        B                    
     a    b    c    d    e    a    b    c    d    e
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

print(df.loc[0,'A'])
a    0.0
b    0.0
c    0.0
d    0.0
e    0.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64

values = pd.Series(range(1,6), index=['a','b','c','d','e'])
print(values)
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
e    5
dtype: float64

df.loc[0,'A'] = values
print(df)
     A                        B                    
     a    b    c    d    e    a    b    c    d    e
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

The desired output should be

```
print(df)
    A                        B                    
     a    b    c    d    e    a    b    c    d    e
0    1    2    3    4    5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Also, to be clear, `series` is used to input values because the values can be ordered in different ways and the indices of the series need to be checked and matched with the `level 1` columns names of the dataframe.

**Add 1**

I have found that giving the series a `MultiIndex` works:

```py
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']])
values = pd.Series(range(1,6), index=idx)
print(values)
A  a    1
   b    2
   c    3
   d    4
   e    5
dtype: int64

df.loc[0,'A'] = values
print(df)
A                        B                    
     a    b    c    d    e    a    b    c    d    e
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: ok, so i tried it with this : ```df.loc[0,'A'] = values.array``` assigning the array values directly and it worked without any settingwithcopy warning. i guess assigning  requires the array/raw values. someone with a well thought answer could possibly jump in here

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this risks wrong assignment since the index is dropped from the Series.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for your comment. The output should the a dataframe with values from the series (above it's the same value of `1` but in general it is not constant) assigned to the dataframe (so in the above, it should be `1s` instead of `NaNs`.

Comment: @Andrew  I did try tuples but it didn't work: the `df` still has `NaNs` instead of values from the series.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for your comment, bu I can't "just use a scalar" - the above is only an example where series contains the same value, but in general it doesn't.

Comment: @Andrew But I need to ensure that indices are correctly matched: an array or a list does not guarantee this since element might be ordered differently.

Comment: I've got a similar problem, except in my case the values I'm assigning are in a DataFrame with a two-level MultiIndex, not a Series, and I"m trying to assign to a DataFrame with a 3-level index (that is, I'm trying to assign to the block matching a single level-one value). I tried the trick under "Add 1", and the hitch is that when I try to transform the two-level DataFrame to a three-level DataFrame (e.g., `df3 = DataFrame(df2, index = MultiIndex.from_product([[level1_value], x, y])`, the values don't get assigned to the new 3-level DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the numpy array rather than the series.

```
df.loc[0,'A'] = values.values
```

or loop through the series index and assign the values

```
for i in values.index:
    df.at[0,('A',i)] = values.at[i]
```

or you can make sure the the two indexes match, and then assign using an index slice

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(3,10)), columns=columns)

idx = pd.IndexSlice

ind = pd.Index([('A', 'a'),
            ('A', 'b'),
            ('A', 'c'),
            ('A', 'd'),
            ('A', 'e')])

values = pd.Series(np.ones(5), index=ind)

df.loc[0, idx['A', :]] = values

print(df)

     A                        B                    
     a    b    c    d    e    a    b    c    d    e
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: The loss of index from series when using `.values` risks wrong assignment since so checking is performed.

Comment: True. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Yes, the update works, but I am surprised that it requires a loop for this.

Comment: Updated my answer to include a final solution which maintains the index but omits a loop.

Comment: Thank you, I already figured this trick of adding MultiIndex to Series two days ago (see my Add 1).